# Jacobians of curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties

I'm only looking for some references.
So I understand that if $C$ is a smooth curve of genus $g>1$, we have an injection $$C^{(2)}\rightarrow J(C),$$ $$(P,Q)\mapsto [P+Q-D_0]$$ where $C^{(2)}$ is a symmetric product and $D_0$ is an arbitrary but fixed divisor in $Div(C)$ of order 2. I have also seen somewhere that this map is an isomorphism if we exclude the zero divisor.

I only want to find the proof of these 2 facts somewhere in literature since I can't seem to prove it myself, but all the proofs I was able to find were too general and I couldn't understand them.

Comment: If genus is zero or one the above map is not injective. (Any way what is the map? Difference of two points?) If genus is greater than or equal to three, the map can not be onto, since the symmetric product has dimension two while $J(C)$ has dimension $g$.

Comment: @Mohan I edited the question, thanks for the comments.

Comment: Aren't you thinking of the canonical map $C^{(g)}\to J(C)$ by $(P_1,\ldots,P_g)\mapsto \sum P_i - D_0$?

Comment: @doetoe yes, that's the map I'm thinking about